# Get JavaScript GoogleMaps coordinates with web-scraping

Tags: r, web-scraping

I want to get coordinates of each real estate ([webpage](http://www.oferty.net/mieszkanie-na-sprzedaz-os-jana-iii-sobieskiego-poznan-inne,918281305)) which I can obtain from this part of webpage code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[

  var GMap_1 = null;
  //  Call this function when the page has been loaded
  function GMap_initialize_1()
  {
    var mapOptions = {
      scrollwheel: 0,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3824, 16.8798),
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      mapTypeControl: true,
      mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
    };
    GMap_1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("GMap_map_1"), mapOptions);
    iconPrecision = new google.maps.MarkerImage("/images/precisionIcon2.png"); iconPrecision.iconSize = new google.maps.Size(12,20);iconPrecision.iconAnchor = new google.maps.Point(6,20);iconPrecision.infoWindowAnchor = new google.maps.Point(6,3);iconPrecision.shadow = "";iconPrecision.shadowSize = new google.maps.Size(22,20);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon: iconPrecision,
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(52.3824, 16.8798),
      map: GMap_1
    });


  }
GMap_initialize_1();
    //]]>
  </script>
```

My code looks like this:

```
url<-"http://www.oferty.net/mieszkanie-na-sprzedaz-os-jana-iii-sobieskiego-poznan-inne,918281305"
doc<-htmlParse(url)
wsp<-xpathApply(doc,"//script[@type='text/javascript']", xmlValue)
geocode<-strsplit(wsp,"google.maps.LatLng\\(")[[1]][3]
geocode<-strsplit(geocode,"\\)")[[1]][1]
Lat<-as.numeric(strsplit(geocode,", ")[[1]][1])
Lng<-as.numeric(strsplit(geocode,", ")[[1]][2])
```

Do you think there is better way to do this? I didn't find any example of scraping javascript parts of html code with package XML or Rcurl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regexpr to grab coordinates.

```
url<-"http://www.oferty.net/mieszkanie-na-sprzedaz-os-jana-iii-sobieskiego-poznan-inne,918281305" 
page <- getURL(url)
pos <- regexpr("LatLng\\((\\d{2}\\.\\d{4}), (\\d{2}\\.\\d{4})\\)", page, perl=TRUE)
LatLng <- unlist(lapply(attr(pos,"capture.start"),
                 function(x,y) as.numeric(substr(y,x,x+6)),y=page))
```

Comment: Great function, I need to get more familiar with this and other text functions. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a way to change digits to, let say <1,4> ? Because coordinates are written in many different ways..

Comment: You can change number of digits, \\d{1,} - one or more, \\d{2,6} - between 2 and 6 (including 2 and 6).